# When converting custom list to string e.g.List.toString in JsonArray then facing performance time issue, do we other way to improve performance time

Tags: java, json-arrayagg

When converting custom object list to string using toString method it increases performance time

```
list<CustomObject> list;
```

JSONArray array = new JSONArray(list.toString());

Comment: What do you mean by "increases performance time"? What exactly do you want to achieve? For most situations, `List.toString` is not suitable. But we need to know more.

Comment: Performance time refers to time complexity..do we have other way to achieve same task in minimum time complexity